# How to split the Options Configured in Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core project where I Configured different options. Now it looks more complex, so I need to split each in to different methods.

For Example I registered mongo db credentials options and I need to move this to simple extension methods:

```
services.Configure<DataAccess.MongoDB.Contracts.AppSettings.MongoDBSettings> options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString
                = GetConfigurationSection("MongoConnection:ConnectionString");
            options.Database
                = GetConfigurationSection("MongoConnection:Database");
        });
```

Expected something like this:

```
services.ConfigureMongoDbSettings();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code to a class like this (you can name it whatever you like):

```
public static class MongoDbSettingsCollectionExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureMongoDbSettings(
                  this IServiceCollection services,
                  IConfiguration Configuration) {
      services.Configure<DataAccess.MongoDB.Contracts.AppSettings.MongoDBSettings> options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString
                = Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("MongoConnection:ConnectionString");
            options.Database
                = Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("MongoConnection:Database");
        });
      return services;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to call it in `Startup` as you suggested:

```
services.ConfigureMongoDbSettings(Configuration);
```

Alternatively, you can pass it the configuration section itself which is what the Core team did with some services:

```
services.ConfigureMongoDbSettings(Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("MongoConnection"));
```

Obviously, in this way you'll have to change the `ConfigureMongoDbSettings()` function above to receive and work directly with the configuration section.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

so in this case i need to pass the IConfiguration ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. You pass it the `IConfiguration`. I will update my answer.

Comment: Any way to inject this inside the IConfiguration in that static class ?

Comment: It's a static class. How can you inject anything in it? Things are injected in the constructor, then you assign them to class fields and use those in the methods. Static functions cannot reach class fields because they cannot reach instances of the class.

Comment: Yes, i know static class cannot be use like that...i am checking for any way to access the Configuration inside the static class with out passing.

Comment: public class Startup
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
}

Like this and use this inside the extension class ...don't know this will have any impact!!

Comment: Instead of passing `Configuration`, you can simply pass it the config section like the Core team did in the template code: `services.ConfigureMongoDbSettings(Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("MongoConnection"));`. And inside the extension method, read the config section directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200914/discussion-between-sujeshkc-and-racil-hilan).

Comment: Making the `Configuration` property static will work properly as you expect it. You'll have to make the associated field as static too and then it cannot be injected. I will update my answer with the option to pass the config section.

Comment: var configuration = Startup.Configuration;

yes, i think inside the extension method we can access like this